# reading and parsing chinese characters from xml

Tags: java, character-encoding

When I am reading the chinese characters from xml file, I am getting some illegal or incorrectly encoded characters. I am not able to parse the xml file using DOM/SAX even.I tried to specify the encoding "UTF-8", but still i am not getting correct output. Sometimes I am getting question marks(?) instead of chinese characters.

And exactly my requirement is, I have an xml file with chinese characeters. I need to read and parse the chinese characters from the file then i need to put it back in a another file as it is.
Please help me to resolve this. here is my code.

**TestMain.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\temp\\myInputFile.txt")));
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        System.out.println(out.toString());
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(domSource, result);
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Sender.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Sender sender = (Sender) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(writer.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
        System.out.println(sender.toString());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\myOutputFile.txt");
        fos.write(sender.toString().getBytes());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

**Sender.java**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "name" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "sender")
public class Sender {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "<sender><name>"+this.name+"</name></sender>";
    }
}
```

**myInputFile.txt**

```
<sender><name>奥迪普时装(深圳)有限公司</name></sender>
```

**myOutputFile.txt**

```
<sender><name>奥迪普时装(深圳)有陿公忸</name></sender>
```

In output file, we can see the difference in 1st & 3rd characters from right to left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution for this.

We need to use UTF-8 charset encoding for inputstream while reading the file and we need to use PrintStream to set UTF-8 encoding for outputstream.

```
//While reading the file
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new 
FileInputStream("C:\\temp\\myInputFile.txt"), "UTF-8"));

//While writing the file
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos, true, "UTF-8");
ps.print(sender.toString());
ps.close();
```